# MySQL import issues

Tags: mysql, wordpress

My sql script has these symbols â€ instead of a '

and when I import all the text that has ' is cut off, so text is missing. (using wordpress) How do i import my DB script without these cuts? is there a way to convert the symbols to ' again when importing? (Yes i selectd utf8 when importing, and yes all tables have CHARSET=utf8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you open your database file in a text editer?
If so, it may mess up its character set.

You can fix it by executing some SQL queries.

Here's some [example code](https://digwp.com/2011/07/clean-up-weird-characters-in-database) that solves a similar problem.

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'â€œ', '“');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'â€', '”');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'â€™', '’');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'â€˜', '‘');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'â€”', '–');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'â€“', '—');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'â€¢', '-');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'â€¦', '…');
```

Comment: The problem is that, i can not Import the database to do an UPDATE commands, during the import i loose the text, so what I did is use the Escape Characters for MySQL  \-, \' etc. and fixed it. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

All i did is use the Escape Characters for MySQL like \' ... \" etc for the characters that were strange.